# What is the correct syntax for cin >> when using c++ style strings inside structures?

Tags: c++, string, structure

I'm having a little trouble trying to work out how to combine `std::cin >>` with strings, where the string is inside a structure, like so.

```
#include <iostream> // for cout and cin
#include <string>   // for string

struct Example
{
    std::string SomeString;
};

int main()
{
    std::cin >> Example.SomeString;    // ERROR!
}
```

Comment: You'd first need to create a variable of type `Example`.

Comment: @Hiura: `return 0` is implied and unnecessary in this question which as a completely unrelated point.

Comment: @KerrekSB I know it's not mandatory but I think it's always good to return something from a function, even from the main, for consistency. Different school, I guess.

Comment: @Hiura: Perhaps so, but in this case (a SO question) it's just noise and gets in the way.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Let me disagree with you and let it be so. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at first to define an object of the structure type where you are going to read data. For example

```
#include <iostream> // for cout and cin
#include <string>   // for string

struct Example
{
    std::string SomeString;
};

int main()
{
    Example e;
    std::cin >> e.SomeString;
}
```

If the data member is defined as static then the syntax will look like

```
#include <iostream> // for cout and cin
#include <string>   // for string

struct Example
{
    static std::string SomeString;
};

std::string Example::SomeString;

int main()
{
    std::cin >> Example::SomeString;
}
```

Here is an example that combines the preceding two.

```
#include <iostream> // for cout and cin
#include <string>   // for string

struct Example
{
    std::string SomeString;
    static std::string OtherString;
};

std::string Example::OtherString;

int main()
{
    Example e1;

    std::cin >> e1.SomeString;

    Example *e2 = &e1;

    std::cin >> e2->SomeString;

    std::cin >> Example::OtherString;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm tired. Yes. Even using the object you described it still gives an error.

Comment: I don't suppose you're going to get around to telling us what that error is? Or perhaps we should just guess? The first snippet [works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b21a343b1ba4895), so if you have trouble with it then you're going to have to _explain_ that trouble.

Comment: For some reason even using your example of std::cin >> e1.SomeString; I receive an error.

Comment: Sorry. Nevermind. The question has been answered. It was just a silly unrelated syntax error that I kept missing for some reason or other.

Comment: You are not running the code verbatim. You changed something.

Comment: @IXL Xeric  It seems you forgot to include <string> or specify name space std:: before standard typenames.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Thanks for your help. I was adding [ArraySize] to the end of std::string SomeString;

like... std::string SomeString[ArraySize];    ... and I couldn't see it for some reason....

Comment: I hope we have learnt something here today! Glad you got it working.

Comment: yes! Also thank you @VladfromMoscow for your answer, which was correct.

I am slowly learning C++ syntax. Arrays are for c-style strings not c++ style strings. By effect I was creating an array of strings.